# How to organise data with specific labels into new columns?

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

The table looks like

```
----------------------------
|Date         |label |data |
----------------------------
|"2018-01-01" |"A"   |1.01 |
----------------------------
|"2018-01-02" |"A"   |1.02 |
----------------------------
|"2018-01-01" |"B"   |2.01 |
----------------------------
|"2018-01-02" |"B"   |2.02 |
----------------------------
|"2018-01-01" |"C"   |3.01 |
----------------------------
|"2018-01-02" |"C"   |3.02 |
----------------------------
|"2018-01-01" |"D"   |4.01 |
----------------------------
|"2018-01-02" |"D"   |4.02 |
----------------------------
```

I would like to select data having the following format:

```
---------------------------------------
|Date         |"A"  |"B"  |"C"  |"D"  |
---------------------------------------
|"2018-01-01" |1.01 |2.01 |3.01 |4.01 |
---------------------------------------
|"2018-01-02" |1.02 |2.02 |3.02 |4.02 |
---------------------------------------
```

In my database, there are thousands of labels, so I am looking for a method to automatically organize the time series data by labels, and then use the labels as the column names.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't support `pivot` (which I don't particularly like anyway), so use conditional aggregation:

```
select date,
       max(case when label = 'a' then data end) as a,
       max(case when label = 'b' then data end) as b,
       max(case when label = 'c' then data end) as c,
       max(case when label = 'd' then data end) as d
from t
group by date;
```

Unfortunately, SQL queries have a fixed set of columns.  So, if you have a variable number of tags, you will need to use dynamic SQL to generate the statement.  That is, you will need to construct the query as string and then execute it.

Also, databases have a maximum limit on the number of columns in a table and a result set.  In SQLite, I think the default limit is 2,000 columns.  That limits the number of values you can have.

Comment: What if I have 1,000 distinct labels? Is there a method that I do not have to explicitly write the labels in the query?

Comment: @Isaac . . . You can generate the code.  One method is to query for the labels in the data, drop the results in a spreadsheet, and then use spreadsheet functionality to generate the code.